# How can I see which nuget packages I've used on my previous project in Github?

Tags: macos, github, c#-5.0

I want to see which nuget packages I've used on one of my old projects that I have stored in GitHub.

I've made an c# REST API app back in 2021 with .net 5.0 in visual studio 2019 on my old pc. My new laptop is a Mac

I've searched in google and GitHub and YouTube but I couldn't find any solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/viewing-packages
The version number of the package is in the middle of the right panel.